# Cloudformation template from UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

How to retrieve the cloudformation template from the UI when you are creating manually a resourse?
e.g.
I would like to create a ElastiCache template after pressing the 'Create Redis clusters' button with the related values I have already add into the UI fields

Thanks,

George

I have not found any related tool for that purposes

Comment: Check `former2` tool on github.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly in AWS, but try [Former2](https://former2.com/) to create CloudFormation templates based on existing resources.
I suggest to create a read-only user in IAM to connect with Former2, **DO NOT** use your root or administrator Access Key / Access Secret.